# WooCommerce Scheduled Actions Tab

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, cron, scheduled-tasks

Im hoping someone here can help me find out where this scheduled actions tab has come from in WooCommerce > Status

[image: woocommerce scheduled actions tab]

Would anyone happen to know if this is from a plugin or if its specific to a theme or if its standard WooCommerce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Woocommerce scheduled Actions tab** is part of a feature released since [Woocommerce v3.5](https://woocommerce.wordpress.com/2018/10/23/woocommerce-3-5-is-here/).

They have included the Action Scheduler library used by the WooCommerce Subscriptions plugin and other WooCommerce plugins in WooCommerce core. This new feature provides a robust, scalable background processing solution for developers. In 3.5 webhooks are delivered using this library.

**So that tab is standard Woocommerce since version 3.5 release.**

> That is a big improvement accessible to all plugins instead of using WP cron scheduled tasks.